# PHP command line argument check if its provided or not

Tags: php

I have a php script and i want to provide command line argument in it
example : `php index.php 3 something`.
now i want to check if both arguement is provided or not
if provided then pass "3" (parameter value) to $n
and "something" 2nd parameter value to $other_variable
and also check that more then 3 argument are not provided
3 arguments are

Comment: The reserved, global variable `$argv` is well documented: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Answer (score 0):

If you run your script in the command line you can use the `$argv` variable to access the arguments:

```
$argc = count($argv);

if($argc !== 3) {
    echo 'Only two parameters are supported' . PHP_EOL;
} else {
    //we have the 2 parameters
    $n = $argv[1];
    $other_variable = $argv[2];

    echo 'n: ' . $n . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'other variable: ' . $other_variable . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

cli.php:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

var_dump($argv);
```

Run cli.php :

```
$ php cli.php 3 something
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(7) "cli.php"
  [1] =>
  string(1) "3"
  [2] =>
  string(9) "something"
}
```

You can use `$argv[1]` and `$argv[2]`.

Also you can write custom rules for arguments. Use regular expressions or `explode` in you script to get arguments from `$argv`. For example, you can pass arguments like this `--`. It can be more clear:

```
php cli.php --arg1=value2 --arg2=value2
```